# Can you deconstruct an object while getting reference to object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code.

```
const chai = require("chai");
const {expect} = chai;
```

Is there a way to use object deconstructing to get both a reference to `chai` and `expect` (like above) with a single expression?

For example I thought something like the following was allowed, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
const chai, {expect} = require("chai");
```

Is my syntax just incorrect and there is a way to do something similar to that? Or is this not possible in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, but with the static [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/import) statement.

Comment: @soywod Ahh that's probably what I was thinking of then. So not possible to do when deconstructing an object.

Comment: As far as I know, no.

Answer (score 3):

Not a single expression, but a single statement:

```
const chai = require("chai"),
      {expect} = chai;
```

(You can of course also omit the linebreak)

Answer (score 1):

An "expression" in javascript can contain everything and something more (e.g. `(()=>{...})()` is a "single expression").

As a pointless exercise for example you could write:

```
const {x, xy} = (()=>{ let x = require("x"); return {x:x, xy:x.y}; })();
```

Is that a "single expression"? If not why?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
const { expect, ...chai } = require('chai');
```

Which would give you `expect`, and `chai` **without** the `expect` function.